# VLC Player - disable file path in play list

Tags: vlc-media-player

The question was already asked in 2007 [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=35117) and the answer was that version 0.9 will do that by default. I am using VLC Player 3.0.12 on Windows 10 and it still shows the full path to the media files - and that's very annoying.

Is there a way to disable file path in play list?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Open VLC Player
2. Click on the "View" menu
3. Select "Playlist"
4. Right-click anywhere in the playlist and select "View Playlist
   columns"
5. Uncheck "File path"

Other solution:
Play with these options and see what suits you the best:

1. View > Playlist > Right-click on the top columns menu and check/uncheck the items.
   OR
2. View > Playlist View Mode

[image: Attached the image for your better visibility. Hope it helps!]

Comment: Sorry I can't find such an option - https://imgur.com/zAMYt3Y

Comment: Added another solution and attached image too. Hope it helps.